# Read variable value from less css parse tree

Tags: less

I have a less css parse tree and I would like to read the value of a variable that's been defined in the less source file. I'm wondering how best to do this. Hacking around in the debugger I've found that I can get the value like this:

```
tree.variable('@font').value.eval().value
```

I'm wondering if that's the right way to do it, or if there's some better way.

Thanks,
Jesse

Comment: +1 for helping me figure this out!